# Keeping track of a list of integers in C, and sampling from the list

Tags: c++, c

Let's just say that at the simplest, I have a function that generates random integers. Every number generated I want to tack onto the end of the list.

Then, at the end, I want to sample a random numbers from this list.

I'm quite newb at C, manoeuvring around singly-linked lists and pointer arguments, so any advice would be welcome.

**edit:** I have no problem switching to C++ if there are structures that would help me out. I just need lists and sampling.

Comment: It's really hard to google things like "set" and "C" because of how general the words are :/

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. If the numbers are already random, why would you need to pull from the list randomly? Walking through in order would be just fine.

Comment: I've tried a singly-linked list + keeping track of its size separately, then getting a random integer upto the size of the list and walking through the list that number of times to pull the selected item. The random condition is just an abstraction, the numbers I tack on are not truly random.

Comment: Wait you have already tried a linked list? and this does not work?

Comment: I'm just very new at C. I'm trying to replicate Python behaviour in C, but very open to switching up they way I do things if there's a better way.

Comment: Learn in C -- period. It will make you a better programmer and help your understanding immensely if you later choose to write in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you know how many elements you will be putting into your list
then you can just do this

```
 double array[100] // or whateversize you want
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   array[i] = yourRandomNumber;
 }

 double index = Rand(0,100);
 return array[index];
```

Keep in mind I did not do the correct sytax for 'yourRandomNumber' and the `Rand` function. This is just an outline of what you can do.

Your second option is to create a mutable list if you do not know the size of the list before hand. I.e basically a C++ vector. This has to be coded by hand.

```
 typedef struct
{
    size_t elementsAllocated;
    size_t elementsUsed;
    int* buffer;
} vector;

 vector* push_front(vector* v, int item)
 {
    if (elementsUsed == elementsAllocated)
    {
        // Time to grow the buffer.
        int elementsAllocated = v->elementsAllocated * 2;
        if (elementsAllocated <= v->elementsAllocated)
        {
          abort(); // Overflow occurred.
        }

        int* buffer = realloc(v->buffer, elementsAllocated * sizeof *buffer);
        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
          abort();
        }

        // Shift the existing data over.
         memmove(buffer + elementsAllocated - v->elementsUsed,
               buffer + v->elementsAllocated - v->elementsUsed,
               v->elementsUsed * sizeof *buffer);
        v->buffer = buffer;
        v->elementsAllocated = elementsAllocated;
   }

   // Prepend the new item.
    int* p = v->buffer + v->elementsAllocated - v->elementsUsed - 1;
    *p = item;
    v->elementsUsed++;
   return p;
}
```

Using std::vectors in c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 int main(){
     std::vector<double> myVec;

     while(cin){ // this lines syntax is not correct because I don't know how you are 
                 // getting your values
       myVec.push_back(value);
     }

     std::cout << myVec[Rand(0, myVec.size())] << std::endl;

 }
```

All the syntax is not correct I.e `cin` and `rand` because I don't know how you are gettting your inputs and Rand can be implemented differently. BUT the rest should be straight forward.

Comment: I do not know the array size beforehand. I'm basically sampling points, and tacking them on if they meet certain conditions. In python it's just random.choice(list) and list.append(item), but obviously I'm learning new stuff with C.

Comment: Can you use c++ it would make your life a lot easier

Comment: I'm basically just moving from Python to C to accelerate a sampling function.

Comment: Use C++. Especially for problems like this. You could use `c++ vectors` for mutable lists where you could just `push` to the end of the list as you would in python

Comment: If you're not busy, would you mind showing me how to do the whole script using vectors? I'm googling their usage at the moment but seeing an implementation would really help.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here's a go at it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int size = 0;
    int capacity = 4;
    int *data = malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        // Allocate more space
        if (size == capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
            data = realloc(data, capacity * sizeof(int));
            if (data == NULL)
                exit(-1);
        }

        // Append a random number
        data[size] = rand();
        size++;
    }

    // Choose a random number (poorly)
    printf("%d\n", data[rand() % size]);
}
```

#### Now, why is this code terrible?

1. `rand()` is terrible. It's allowed to return random numbers in the range `[0, 32768)`. Or larger if your implementation supports it.
2. `rand()` is allowed to use relatively terrible algorithms to generate random numbers.
3. `rand() % size` is not necessarily uniform.
4. `time(NULL)` is a terrible seed. `time(NULL)` returns the current time with a precision of **seconds**. So if I run this code twice quickly, it will often return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance at least an upper bound on the count of points you may accept, then you can use a variation on @Jay's answer.  Otherwise, you need some kind of dynamic allocation.  You could use a linked list and allocate nodes as you go, but it might be faster and easier to simply `malloc()` an array and `realloc()` if you find you need more space:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double select_one() {
    int capacity = 100;
    int count;
    double rval;
    double *accepted = malloc(capacity * sizeof(double));

    // accepted == NULL on malloc() failure
    count = 0;

    while (/* more points to test */) {
        double point = /* next point to test */;

        if (/* point is accepted */) {
            if (count >= capacity) {
                /* expand the array */
                double *temp;

                capacity = 3 * capacity / 2;
                temp = realloc(accepted, capacity * sizeof(double));
                if (temp == NULL) {
                    /* need to handle allocation failure to avoid a memory leak */
                } else {
                    accepted = temp;
                }
            }

            accepted[count++] = point;
        }
    }

    /* Note: not perfectly uniform because of the modulus */
    rval = accepted[rand() % count];

    /* clean up the allocated memory, AFTER selecting the value */
    free(accepted);

    return rval;
}
```